# Mouse click detection with no focus at mainwindow qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to detect mouse button presses even when I lose focus of my mainwindow but can't find a working solution for me. I have already done similar thing in console c++. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND hWND = NULL;
    bool is_going = false;
    while (true) {
        Sleep(50);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0)) return 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1)) {
            POINT p;
            GetCursorPos(&p);
            ScreenToClient(hWND, &p);
            cout << "x-pos: " << p.x << " | y-pos: " << p.y << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD2)) {
            cout << boolalpha << is_going << " ";
            if (is_going) is_going = false;
            else is_going = true;
            cout << is_going << endl;
        }
        if (is_going) {
            INPUT input = { 0 };
            input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
            ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(input));
            input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
        }
        
    }
}
```

But now I am writing an autoclicker in Qt c++ and I want to be able to start it with a key binding even if my app isn't on top. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "Hook". It can catch mouse (or others) events while non-top, not active, etc.
See: SetWindowsHookEx. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa

Comment: Just in case, you can use crossplatform library that can do what you want: https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook